# Populating dropdown list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown list. These two are not interdependent on each other.

The values in the first dropdown list are `[ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]`.
The values in second dropdown are `[ 'ten', 'nine', 'eight', 'seven' ]`.
If I select `two` in the first dropdown then second dropdown should be auto-populated with `nine`.

I have tried this.

```
var value1=document.getElementById('ddlone').value;
if(vaue1=='two'){
    document.getElementById('ddlone').selectedValue='nine';
} else {
    document.getElementById('ddlone').selectedValue='';
}
```

But I didn't get the expected result. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You need to add event handler for event `change` on first select. There you define a function which will be executed by browser when user changes value of first selector. And you can define your code there to programmaticaly change selected value of second selector, like you did in your code.

Comment: ***[Here's a nice example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent2.shtml)***

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<select id="first">
    <option>select</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option>select</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>7</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#first').on('change', function () {
        var vall = $(this).find('option:selected').index()
        $('#second').find('option').eq(vall).prop('selected', true)
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8YqKc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="sel1">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
    <option value="5">five</option>
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
    <option value="8">eight</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#sel1").on('change', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value == '2' ){
            $("#sel2").val('7');
        }
    });
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/zE73L/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<select id="first" onchange="change_second(this.value);">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
    <option value="four">four</option>
</select>


<select id="second">
     <option value="ten">ten</option>
    <option value="nine">nine</option>
    <option value="eight">eight</option>
    <option value="seven">seven</option>

</select>
```

**JS :**

```
function change_second(val)
{
    var elmnt1 = document.getElementById('first');    
    var elmnt2 = document.getElementById('second');

    var desired_index = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < elmnt1.options.length; i++)
    {
          if(elmnt1.options[i].value === val) {
          desired_index = i;
          break;
        }
     }

    elmnt2.selectedIndex = desired_index;

}
```

SEE **[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sJ8bj/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an onchange event to the first drop down and call one function and have to change the value of second drop down.

Here the code

```
<html>
 <script>
 function populatedrop2(){
  var value= document.getElementById("drop1").value;
  if(value == "two"){
   document.getElementById("drop2").value = "nine";
  }
}
 </script>
 <body>
   <select id="drop1" onchange=populatedrop2();>
     <option value="one">one</option>
     <option value="two">two</option>
     <option value="three">three</option>
     <option value="four">four</option>
   </select>

   <select id="drop2">
     <option value="seven">seven</option>
     <option value="eight">eight</option>
     <option value="nine">nine</option>
     <option value="ten">ten</option>
   </select>

 </body>
</html>
```

Best of Luck